# ConvNet for Archery App

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I'm looking at trying to build a model to score an archery end from a photo but i'm not sure about the optimal ConvNet architecture.  What output neurons would I use given I can have an unknown number of arrows in a photo?  I could do a regression type solution of 'total score' I guess but i'd like to get a per arrow score (or perhaps the x,y coordinates of each arrow on a projected grid).

Any thoughts, wisdom, etc would be appreciated.  I'm likely not quite thinking about this the right way.